# Save a 3 dimensional array from R to a format to be read by Python numpy

Tags: python, r, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a 3-dimensional array in R (numerical), which I want to *transfer* to Python, i.e. to a 3-dimensional numpy array. How can I do this? I have tried several options, but all of them *destroy* the 3rd dimension.

Comment: What about converting it to a JSON string in R and reading this JSON string in Python?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please give a [mre] in your question!

Comment: @jogo I do not think a mre is necessary for this question, it is pretty clear.

Comment: There is an interface to write read/write native binary numpy-files in R. http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.cnpy.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reticulate to convert the array from R to python. Then save it using numpy (called from within R).

```
## inside R

library(reticulate)
x = array(runif(27),dim=c(3,3,3))
# import numpy
np = import("numpy")
np$save("test.npy",r_to_py(x))
```

Now we load it with python:

```
import numpy as np                                                      
np.load("test.npy")                                                     
array([[[0.53035511, 0.09324333, 0.74165792],
        [0.32596559, 0.84278233, 0.63397294],
        [0.71819993, 0.69992033, 0.23523802]],

       [[0.4240157 , 0.92849409, 0.23161098],
        [0.82145088, 0.789411  , 0.18161145],
        [0.87357443, 0.29713062, 0.35034028]],

       [[0.17399566, 0.81314384, 0.92519895],
        [0.72759271, 0.62621744, 0.02139281],
        [0.39817859, 0.62391164, 0.66426406]]])
```